# Responsive table con materialize css

Tags: css, materialize

estoy teniendo problemas al cuadrar la cabecera de una tabla responsive de materialize con su cuerpo cuando uso botones dentro de la tabla... ¿Alguien tiene idea de cómo puedo cuadrarla? Me estyp refiriendo al descuadre vertical de a cual encabezado corresponde cada celda.

[image: Ejemplo de responsive table]

```
</div>
<table class="table striped responsive-table centered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Ganador</th>
            <th scope="col">Premio</th>
            <th scope="col">Responsable</th>
            <th scope="col">Entregado</th>
            <th scope="col">Notas</th>
            <th scope="col">Partner</th>
            <th scope="col">Campaña</th>
            <th scope="col">Inicio</th>
            <th scope="col">Entrega</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            $giveaways = Giveaway::getGiveaway($_SESSION['init']);
            foreach($giveaways as $g){
                if($g['delivered'] == '0'){
                    $buttonDelivered = '<a class="btn-small red" href="index.php?isDeliveredGA&giveawayId='.$g['id'].'"><i class="material-icons">close</i></a>';
                }else{
                    $buttonDelivered = '<a class="btn-small green"><i class="material-icons">done</i></a>';
                }
                if($g['responsible'] == null){
                    $buttonResponsible = '<a class="btn-small red" href="index.php?isResponsible&giveawayId='.$g['id'].'"><i class="material-icons">how_to_reg</i></a>';
                }else{
                    $buttonResponsible = '<a class="btn-small blue">'.$g['responsible'].'</a>';
                }
                if($g['notes'] == 1){
                    $notesButton = '<a class="btn-small blue" href="index.php?getNote&giveawayId='.$g['id'].'"><i class="material-icons">description</i></a>';
                }else{
                    $notesButton = '<a class="btn-small orange" href="index.php?insertNote&giveawayId='.$g['id'].'"><i class="material-icons">create</i></a>';
                }

                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$g['winner'].'</td><td>'.$g['item'].'</td><td>'.$buttonResponsible.'</td><td>'.$buttonDelivered.'</td><td>'.$notesButton.'</td><td>'.$g['partner'].'</td><td>'.$g['serie'].'</td><td>'.Utils::getDateFormat($g['startDate']).'</td><td>'.Utils::getDateFormat($g['deliveredDate']).'</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Comparte el código que estás utilizando, describe mejor el problema que tienes y qué es lo que quieres.

Comment: Buenas, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, no sé en qué puede ayudarte mi código, es un framework de css, uso la clase responsive-table en una tabla que itero con php. Lo que me ocurre es lo que muestro en la foto, el cabecero de la tabla se desencuadra con los valores de las celdas al añadir botones en este.

Comment: Buenas, subi el codigo con el q armas la tabla, el html, el css (o sea los div y clases de materialize) y rellenalo asi para q podamos ejecutar ese codigo nosotrso y podamos ver el error. (Hacelo siempre, sino te pueden tirar abajo la pregunta porque no cumplis con las reglas de la comunidad)

Comment: Por otro lado, tu tabla tiene mas registros? Porque el responsive de materialize no acomoda la tabla y las columnas solo las ordena de izquierda a derecha, o sea que podes empezar a mover para la derecha para ir viendo todos los registros.

Comment: @Juan gracias por la ayuda, he incluido el código. En cuanto a css no tengo nada añadido. Me refiero al descuadre vertical de cada celda con su cabecera.

Comment: Hermano, quedaria mejor una captura de pantalla para ver bien. Otra cosa, es este el framework? https://materializecss.com/

Comment: Tu problema claramente es CSS, una solución que puedes probar es aplicar la propiedad `min-height: 4.5em;` a tus elementos `tr` y `th`. Nota: El `4.5em` se aplica suponiendo que conservas el tamaño de fuente por defecto que es `14px`. Si tienes alguna duda nos avisas.

Comment: Efectivamente era esto, muchas gracias por la ayuda porque no conseguía sacarlo @Jheyman